# Unable to Modify the X Axis Tick Locator in ACF, PACF plots in statsmodels, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, advanced-custom-fields, statsmodels

I wanted to modify the X Axis tick for the ACF & PACF Plots i.e. I wanted a tick after every 2 & 4 units (minor & major ticks) in stead of the default 20 units that was coming. I was trying the following code :

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf,plot_pacf

rcParams['figure.figsize']=20,10
ax = plt.subplot(211)
plot_acf(ts_log_diff) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator=4) 
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator=2)
plt.subplot(212)
plot_pacf(ts_log_diff, ax=plt.gca())
plt.show()
```

The error message I am getting is :

```
File "<ipython-input-99-bfa377e377fd>", line 5
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator=4) 
                          ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I had used a similar syntax with pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot and it was working :

```
plotacf= pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(ts_log_diff)
plotacf.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(2))
plotacf.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator( 4))
```

Comment: I am not sure about other code, but in Python, you can't use dots in keyword arguments - (plt.MultipleLocator=4)`

Why don't you use the following?ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(4))

Comment: Thanks man. My bad. That was the issue with the syntax. Yes, this syntax worked :

Answer (score 1):

*To close this question, I moved from comment to answer.*

The issue with your code was that you used a keyword argument with a dot - and that is invalid syntax. But you didn't need to use keyword arguments at all. Instead, you need to call the following:

`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(4))`

I recommend checking more about keyword arguments, so you would understand the syntax.

**Keyword argument example:**

*For example, you have a function:*

```
from math import sqrt

def quadratic(a, b, c):
    x1 = -b / (2*a)
    x2 = sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c) / (2*a)
    return (x1 + x2), (x1 - x2)
```

You can call `quadratic(31, 93, 62)` or call directly using args names - `quadratic(a=31, b=93, c=62)`

Source: https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/